# Left and right arrow keys not registering onkeypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeypress

I have an on key event that fires fine and registers the space bar when pressed, however the left and right arrow keys do nothing, they simply don't fire.

```
$('html').keypress(function(e) {

            if(e.which == 32) { event.preventDefault(); app.playPauseToggle() }

            else if(e.which == 37) { event.preventDefault(); app.changeTrack('previous') }

            else if(e.which == 39) { event.preventDefault(); app.changeTrack('next'); }

        })
```

I'm certain that my key codes are fine: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

I've tried `console.log` tests under the `if`s and they do nothing either.

Answer (score 2):

`.keypress` ignores arrow keys, you're going to want to use `.keydown` instead.

Comment: great! thanks :) i'll accept when it allows me to :)